# How do I remove dashes, parentheses, and spaces from a phone number?

Tags: swift, string

I have a phone number `String` that is formatted like this: +1 (123) 456-7890 and I want it to be changed to: 1234567890. How would I do that? I tried the code below but it still shows the same format.

```
     let phone = phoneNumber.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "[()\\s-]+", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
     print("phone Number \(phone)")
```

Comment: Replace `.literal` with `.regularExpression`.

Comment: you mean `"11234567890"`